# C++ Passing a member variable to a member class

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I have legacy code where a similar method is used to cycle through a sequential container (vector in this example. Some implementations use other kinds of containers). So I factored it out into a template so I could reuse the same piece of code for any container type.

```
template<template<class, class> class TContainer, class TObject>
class cycle
{
public:

    explicit cycle( TContainer<TObject, std::allocator<TObject>> & container )
        : mContainer( container ), index(0) {}

    TObject getNext(int numObjectsToCycle) 
    { return mContainer[index++ % numObjectsToCycle]; }
private:
    TContainer<TObject, std::allocator<TObject>> & mContainer;
    int index;
};
```

Then my class has a cycler to cycle through my variable numbers.

```
class myClass
{
   std::vector<int> numbers;

public:
   cycle<vector, int> cycler;
   // Is it safe to pass numbers since it is declared first??
   myClass() : cycler(numbers) {} 

};
```

Then, I use the code like below.:

```
myObject.cycler.getNext(size);
```

Is it a good programming practice to pass the vector "numbers" to cycler? Is there a better way of implementing my template?

The code really is to be able to infinitely loop through objects. My class is invoked from external code that just calls a member method, and I want to be able to just call getNext() so I wouldn't have to use an index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the standard library another "pattern" exists and it's the *iterator pattern*. Basically every container type implements `begin` and `end` which returns, respectively, the iterator to the first element and the past-the-end element (which is always guaranteed to exists).

This works for every container type, from `std::vector` to `std::array` including C-style arrays with [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end). If you want to loop in a generic container you can do, for example:

```
template<typename Container>
void cicle(Container const& c) {
    for (auto const& i : c) {
        // …
    }
}
```

or, to better visualize the pattern:

```
template<typename Container>
void cicle(Container const& c) {
    for (auto it = std::begin(c); it != std::end(c); ++it) {
        // …
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1727f5171d80d39a)

Comment: I've updated my question above. I can't do a loop like you've mentioned since myClass will have a public method that is called externally. So I really need to have a member variable index for the loop to work.

Comment: "I can't do a loop like you've mentioned since myClass will have a public method that is called externally." -- I can't see the problem with this approach and your "method" that gets called externally.

Comment: The external code that calls the method intends to process only 1 element for the container. So each call to my public method handles one element in the container only. Hope that clears it up. :)

Comment: I think I understand your point now. I can use the iterator to cycle it.